# pin multiple locations on google maps in browser with python

Tags: python, browser, tabs

I am trying to pin multiple locations on google maps on the same browser tab with Python but can't seem to figure it out. So far I've come up with this to open a singular tab.

```
location = "1235 N MULFORD RD ROCKFORD, IL"
webbrowser.open("https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/"+location)
```

This for example will open one tab with the pin on google maps at the desired location. My first thought was to have all of the locations in a list and loop through it, but doing that just opens up a new google maps tab for each location. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what did you find with `Google` ? First ask `Google` and later ask on `Stackoverflow` or other forums.

Comment: using Google I found that in browser you can set many pins only using [how do I pin multiple locations on a map?](https://support.google.com/maps/thread/37688424?hl=en) but it doesn't keep locations in URL so you can't use it directly. Maybe using modules like `pyautogui` to control mouse/keyboard you could select places on map - or using `Selenium` to control web browser - [How To Pin Point Multiple Locations On Google Maps](https://www.create.net/support/how-to-pin-point-multiple-locations-on-google-maps).

Comment: But I would rather try to use [Google Maps SDK](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python). But usually this is used to create own map on own page and display pin many places on this map.